# Is it UB to cast void* param to various types?

Tags: c++

```
void WorkHorse(void* ptr, int tag) {
   if (SomeFunction(tag)) {
       Foo* foo_ptr = (Foo*)ptr;
       // do stuff
   } else {
       Bar* bar_ptr = (Bar*)ptr;
   }
}
```

I know this is generally a bad design but curious if it's technically UB.

Comment: What's defined is the conversion happens. Is that a valid cast? That's the question.

Comment: True. I guess the question should've been "Is this code UB, assuming `tag` correctly identifies which type to cast to?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it UB to cast void* param to various types?

No, casting `void*` to a pointer to object type is not UB. If it was, then `void*` would be mostly useless.

However, indirecting through the converted pointer may be UB in some cases; typically when the address doesn't contain an object of appropriate type.

As you pointed out, using `void*` like this is typically bad design, and only needed when interacting with some C APIs.

Comment: Assuming the `tag` will correctly identify which type `void*` should be cast to, it'd be fine, yes?

Comment: @CuriousLearner Yeah that should be fine.

Comment: `void*` is OK for object pointers, not function pointers.

Comment: @chux: It is conditionally supported for function pointers. That is, an implementation may choose to support it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I find no support in the C standard about conversions 6.3.2.3 Pointers for conditionally supported of `void *` and function pointers.  Without that it would be  UB.  Perhaps you know of something in C++?

Comment: @chux: C++ [says this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.reinterpret.cast#8)

Comment: @NicolBolas LSNED

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Even in C, while not standard in ISO, it is specified in POSIX standard, so it is quite a common language extension.

Answer (score 0):

The part in your code that I would most take issue with is the style of casting, not what is done with the cast. I would prefer to use `static_cast` instead of the C-style cast. Using the weakest tool that is adequate for the intended job gives the compiler maximum leeway for pointing out questionable code (a.k.a. warnings about possible bugs).

A side benefit of using `static_cast` is that the answer to your question lies directly on the [static_cast conversion page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) @ cppreference.com. Check out point 10, which ends with the following.

> Conversion of any pointer to pointer to void and back to pointer to the original (or more cv-qualified) type preserves its original value.

If you had cast a `Foo*` to `void*` to get the value passed in as `ptr`, then a `static_cast` back to `Foo*` recovers the original value. De-referencing the original value is fine as long as it hasn't become a dangling pointer.

*To be fair to C-style casts, you do get the same results in this situation with either a C-style cast or a `static_cast`. And you could get the documentation starting from the explicit cast page @ cppreference.com – because that page links to the static_cast page. ;)*

---

Also, don't do these conversions unless required by the API. It seems there is agreement on this point, so it's just a footnote for me.